# Is it possible to add webapi to the existing vb.net web application? if so please guide me to do so

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, asp.net-web-api2

I have a `vb.net` web application. I would like to create web-services using WebApi in the same project. I could find help for creating them in C# but not in vb.

Comment: i just searched for "add webapi to vb.net application"  and clicked on the first result.

Comment: thank you.. tried it again but could not find any resource in vb...